# Whats the double differential of a state variable?

Tags: differential-forms

From Thermodynamics (fundamental equation):
\begin{equation}
dh = Tds + vdp
\end{equation}
h=specific enthalpy (Enthalpy/mass); T=Temperature; v=specific volume; s=specific entropy; p=pressure

I want:
\begin{equation}
(\frac{\partial h}{\partial T})_{p=const} \rightarrow dp=0
\end{equation}

Differentiating by product rule yields:
\begin{equation}
(\frac{\partial h}{\partial T})_{p} = (\frac{\partial (Tds)}{\partial T})_{p}\\
= ds + T(\frac{\partial d s}{\partial T})_{p}
\end{equation}

I'm confused by the double differential $\partial d s$. What does this say? The above described method yields a wrong result.

For those interested, I want to derive the Gibbs-Helmholtz equation. I know a derivation from a book, which is a little different. I guess my mistake is that I need to tranform dh(s,p) to dh(T,p) to be able to differntiate by T? But I'm not sure...

Comment: The derivative you want is $\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}$, but instead you took the derivative of the derivative, when you should have taken the derivative of $H = G + TS$. See the mistake?